# PYTHON - Search a directory

Tags: python

Is it possible for the user to input a specific directory on their computer, and for Python to write the all of the file/folder names to a text document? And if so, how?
The reason I ask is because, if you haven't seen my previous posts, I'm learning Python, and I want to write a little program that tracks how many files are added to a specific folder on a daily basis. This program isn't like a project of mine or anything, but I'm writing it to help me further learn Python. The more I write, the more I seem to learn.
I don't need any other help than the original question so far, but help will be appreciated!

Thank you!

EDIT: If there's a way to do this with "pickle", that'd be great! Thanks again!

Comment: Take a look at the documentation for `os.walk`, which will help you identify files/folders under a given folder path. Alternatively, if you just care about a single level, `os.listdir` (and other `os` functions) may come in handy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`os.walk()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk) is what you'll be looking for.  Keep in mind that this doesn't change the current directory your script is executing from; it merely iterates over all possible paths that stem from the arguments to it.

```
for dirpath, dirnames, files in os.walk(os.path.abspath(os.curdir)):
    print files

# insert long (or short) list of files here
```

Comment: That helped very much, but is there any way to get those results to be printed into a .txt file?
Never mind - I figured it out with "pickle". Answer accepted!

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to be using [`os.walk`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk), this will help you in creating a listing of the files down from your directory.

Once you have the listing, you can indeed store it in a file using `pickle`, but that's another problem (i.e.: Pickle is not about *generating* the listing but about *storing* it).

Answer (score 1):

While the approach of @Makato is certainly right, for your 'diff' like application you want to capture the inode 'stat()' information of the files in your directory and pickle that python object from day-to-day looking for updates; this is one way to do it - overkill maybe - but more suitable than save/parse-load from text-files IMO.